# Laravel 5 - SoftDelete not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, eloquent, soft-delete

I've been searching a lot in the web and StackOverflow itself, however I can't find a solution to the problem.

Soft deleting simply refuses to work. The database has the deleted_at field. User model has everything needed to supposedly work, however data is still hard deleted when I call the Delete() method. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Laravel Version: 5.3.31

destroy method

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    //$this->authorize('delete', User::class);
    $user = User::find($id);

    if (empty($user)) {
        Flash::error('User not found');

        return redirect(route('users.index'));
    }

    $user->Delete();

    Flash::success('User deleted successfully.');

    return redirect(route('users.index'));
}
```

user model

```
namespace App\Models;

use Eloquent as Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class User extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public $table = 'users';

    const CREATED_AT = 'created_at';
    const UPDATED_AT = 'updated_at';


    protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];


    public $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'role',
        'remember_token'
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'integer',
        'name' => 'string',
        'email' => 'string',
        'password' => 'string',
        'role' => 'string',
        'remember_token' => 'string'
    ];


    public static $rules = [
      'name' => 'required|max:255',
    ];
}
```

I appreciate anything that can help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why ->Delete() in uppercase? Method should be lowercase. just  ->delete()

Comment: Hello, it harddeletes the record either way.

Comment: What does `use Eloquent as Model` refer to?

Comment: @VaheShak PHP functions are not case sensitive. I know it looks weird but it's still valid.

Comment: Can you show the migration that adds the `deleted_at` field?